# How to change .txt global permissions?

Tags: command-line, permissions, files

[image]I'm trying to read and write to `.txt` files in java but I can't because all of their permissions are set to read only. I could just click on each file's properties individually and change them, but I have a lot of text files and that's impractical. Is there any way to change the global permissions for all `.txt` files to read and write?

You'd think that with this much help it would work, but even after all Zannas methods I can't open the files in java and the permissions don't seem to change.
[image]

Comment: do you mean files with `.txt` extension, or files in text format (if so, ASCII?) and when you say globally, do you mean writable for everyone, not just the owner?

Comment: `.txt` extension files and I assume I need them to be writable by anyone so that my java programs could access them

Comment: if you're using the `for` loop method, you have to run it **without** `echo` after testing (your screenshot show the output from `echo` - `chmod` will not give any output itself)

Answer (score 5):

If the files have an extension `.txt` then you might use something like:

```
find ~/Desktop/Research -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec chmod u+w '{}' +
```

`find` is recursive by default and will go into all subdirectories as well.

If the files are of the *type* text but don't have extensions, you could do something like

```
for i in ~/Desktop/Research/*; do if [[ $(file "$i" | grep text) ]]; then echo chmod u+w "$i"; fi; done
```

In this command, `echo` is just for testing, to show what permission changes will be applied. Remove `echo` after testing to actually change the permissions. This time, there will not be any output.

If you want this command to work on subdirectories, you can do this:

```
shopt -s globstar; for i in ~/Desktop/Research/**; do if [[ $(file "$i" | grep text) ]]; then echo chmod u+w "$i"; fi; done
```

I have used `chmod u+w` which adds write permission only for the owner. Adjust as you prefer, (try this first and if you still have problems, then replace with `chmod o+w` or `chmod 666` but beware of giving write permission to everyone!) And of course, don't change permissions of system files.

Comment: I keep getting
find: ‘/root/home/erlandas/Desktop/Research’: No such file or directory

Comment: @ErlandasAksomaitis I have edited, but make sure you are logged in as `erlandas` and not in a root shell

Comment: So this changes the permissions of any `*.txt` file in that given directory. How would I go about doing for all the directories inside that directory?
I have `~/Desktop/Research/TestNo1/`, there are many other similar directories in Research only changing the number of the test.

Comment: @ErlandasAksomaitis edited again (`find` is recursive by default, and searches in all subdirectories of the specified directory unless you tell it not to)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command

```
find /PATH/TO/FOLDER -iname '*.txt'
```

to list all filenames matching the pattern `*.txt` (i.e. anything ending with `.txt`) recursively inside the directory `/PATH/TO/FOLDER`.

This is useful to check which files will be affected before doing any modifications. If you also want to see those files' owner and permissions at the same time, here you go:

```
find /PATH/TO/FOLDER -iname '*.txt' -exec stat -c '%A %U %n' '{}' \;
```

Now let's get to the real command, the one which actually modifies the permissions. As it stands below, it can only change the permissions of files your current user owns and it will only add write permissions for the owner. I recommend to leave it like that, because otherwise you easily weaken your system's security by accident.

```
find /PATH/TO/FOLDER -iname '*.txt' -exec chmod u+w '{}' \;
```

Also you must of course replace `/PATH/TO/FOLDER` with a valid location in your file system, but please execute this command only on data files you own and never on system directories, especially not on stuff owned by the root user and especially not with `sudo`, unless you want to risk messing up your system and making it unstable and less secure.

Comment: I'm writing this, but it keeps telling me no such file directory

find /root/home/erlandas/Desktop/Research -iname '*.txt' -exec chmod u+w '{}' \;

Comment: There should not be any directory like `/root/home` and you shouldn't do such stuff to root-owned files or do your daily operations as root at all.

Comment: how come there shouldn't be a `/root/home` directory? `root` is start of any file path in linux and `home` is the directory that houses user profiles

Comment: No, `/` is the start of any file path (`/` is "the root" of the directory structure). On the other hand, `/root` is the `root` user's home folder. Completely different thing. @Erlandas.